# How to filter an Array and Update the result in the same Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

what's the best way of filtering an array and keep the result in the same array

for example :

```
var OBJ = function(x, y) {this.x = x; this.y = y};
obj1 = new OBJ(1, 2);
obj2 = new OBJ(2, 3);
obj3 = new OBJ(3, 2);
obj4 = new OBJ(3, 1);
obj5 = new OBJ(4, 5);

var array_1 = new Array(); array_1.push(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5);

var array_2 = array_1.filter(function(el){
    return (el.x > 2);
});
```

OUTPUT :

array_1 = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5];

array_2 = [obj3, obj4, obj5];

I want the array_1 update like array_2

What's the best way?

thanks

Comment: You'll have to write your own "filter" function. What do you plan on doing about array entries that fail the test? Also, why is it important to have the filtering done in-place?

Comment: `var array_1 = array_1.filter(...);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_1 = array_1.filter(function(el){
    return (el.x > 2);
});
```

Simple enough.

Comment: Well, this will work, but it's not really the "same array" :-)

Comment: @Pointy Ah, you're right. Your custom function is better for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it in place, you'd need something like this:

```
function filterInPlace(a, ff) {
  var s, d;

  for (s = d = 0; s < a.length; ++s) {
    if (ff(a[s]))
      a[d++] = a[s];
  }
  a.length = d;
}
```

You'd call it like this:

```
filterInPlace(array_1, function(element) { ... });
```